# Convert a column in CSV to a string in C

Tags: c, csv

So, I was trying to write a program to take the first column of a CSV file and copy that do a string, but it's not going well. I put the code and the CSV file and I really appreciate any help.

```
int main () {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("filePATH", "r");
    char column[80];
    int line_n = 0;
    char ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {

            fgets(column, sizeof column, fp);

            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof column; ++i){
                fscanf(fp, "%[^;]", column);


            }
        printf("%s \n", column);
        }

        fclose(fp);
return 0;
    }

CSV file: 

2;51.5;144.0;24.80
5;62.3;157.0;25.30
10;52.8;141.0;26.60
10;34.5;120.0;24.00
1;41.6;131.0;24.20
5;49.0;144.0;23.80
6;47.1;142.0;23.50
2;51.8;144.5;24.80
1;55.6;135.0;30.50
9;51.9;150.0;23.10
9;48.5;139.0;25.10
```

The output I have is:

```
5 
10 
10 
1 
5 
6 
2 
1 
9 
9 
48.5;139.0;25.10
```

So, I don't understand why the program shows me the first column but copies only the last line for the string column.

To check the string column, I used:

```
char copy[20];

    strncpy(copy, column, 18);

    printf("%s ", copy);
```

And the output is:

```
48.5;139.0;25.10
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't make much sense.  Suppose the first two lines of the file are `a;b\nc;d\n`.  The `fgetc` in the loop reads the `a`, then `fgets` reads `;b\n`.  Then the `scanf` reads `c`.  The first line was read and ignored!

Comment: I'm guessing that's why I never get the first element of the column printed.

Comment: Also, the `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof column; ++i){ fscanf(fp, "%[^;]", column);` is certainly not doing what you expect.  The first iteration of the loop, it will read everything up to the first `;`.  On the 2nd and subsequent iterations of the loop, it tries to read from the stream, but the first character it sees is a `;` so it immediately stops and reads nothing.

Comment: No idea what your first while loop is doing, it's basically useless and causes errors. Don't use both fgets and fgetc. Also, fscanf is a pain for formatting files. Honestly, if you just need first column, I would just use fgets to get column line and maybe strtok(column, ";") to obtain first column value each time. (wouldn't recommend strtok if you're doing more advanced parsing though)

Comment: You probably want to structure your code as `while( fgets ) { sscanf }`.  Read with `fgets` into a buffer, and then use `sscanf` (as opposed to `fscanf`) on that buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll do the recommended changes and, hopefully, it will work! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly you want to restructure the loops, but here are some minimal changes to your code that might be instructive:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char sample_input[] =
    "2;51.5;144.0;24.80\n"
    "5;62.3;157.0;25.30\n"
    "10;52.8;141.0;26.60\n"
    "10;34.5;120.0;24.00\n"
    "1;41.6;131.0;24.20\n"
    "5;49.0;144.0;23.80\n"
    "6;47.1;142.0;23.50\n"
    "2;51.8;144.5;24.80\n"
    "1;55.6;135.0;30.50\n"
    "9;51.9;150.0;23.10\n"
    "9;48.5;139.0;25.10\n"
;

int
main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fmemopen(sample_input, sizeof sample_input, "r");
    char column[80];
    int line_n = 0;
    int ch;  /* fgetc returns an int. */

    while( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF ){
        /* put ch back so it can be read by scanf */
        ungetc(ch, fp);

        /* This fgets does not seem to serve any purpose. 
        /* fgets(column, sizeof column, fp); */

        ch = ';';
        while( ch == ';' && fscanf(fp, "%79[^;\n]", column) == 1 ){
            ch = fgetc(fp);  /* Consume the ; or \n */
            printf("%s%c", column, ch);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

It would probably be better to use the `fgets` to read each line of data and then use `sscanf` to parse the line, but I wanted to show that your current code can be made to (mostly) work with minimal changes.  Note that the variable used to store the value returned by `fgetc` must be `int` rather than `char` in order to properly compare to EOF.  Also, whenever you use `%s` or `%[]` in `scanf`, it is best to add a width modifier to prevent a buffer overflow.